# Using MySQL Regex - Match the first word then second letter of a string

Tags: mysql, regex, database, string

How would you write a MySQL regex pattern that matches the full first word and the first character of the second word in a string. The string does not actually have to begin with a word. Case does not matter.

When searching for a string in which the first word occurrence is "Stack" and the next word begins with "O", the regex pattern should return true for all of the following:

1. -> Stack (Overflow) is great
2. Stack -> Overflow is great
3. Stack Overflow is great

and will fail if "Stack" is not the first word occurrence or the second word does not begin with an "O", like for the following:

1. Is Stack Overflow the best?
2. Stack is Overflow

I have tried some patterns but only came up with the following:

```
SELECT * FROM members WHERE description REGEX '^[[:<:]]Stack[[:>:]].+[[:<:]]O'
```

The problem here is:

1. It only matches strings that actually start with "Stack" but it should also match also strings like `+=,Stack`
2. It matches anything between and even words between "Stack" and "Overflow"

It will work if I can find the first and second word boundary.

Answer (score 1):

I think this expression does what you want:

```
 where description rlike '^[^a-zA-Z]*Stack [^a-zA-Z]*O'
```

Comment: Numbers matter in this case. I took your helpful answer and came up with `^[^A-Za-z0-9]*Stack[^A-Za-z0-9]*O` which works correctly.